# Structured chain of functions

Tags: binary-operations

It is a trivial assertion that the binary operation $g(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is associative and also distributive over the binary operation $f(x,y)\mapsto x+y$. We say that $f\leadsto g$ if this occurs, where all the binary operations in consideration are taken over the reals. The question is to determine whether the longest possible chain of functions
$$f_1\leadsto f_2\leadsto f_3\leadsto f_4...$$
is finite.

Comment: Must the functions $f_i$ all be distinct?

Comment: Well, I need something more than a triviality, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

With some minor tweaks (work over complexes, etc.) you can get an infinite chain. See: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0112050.